# Expose file from blocked directory to user on Linux?

Tags: linux, permissions

I'm running a web server on my (virtual root) server where a friend is allowed to host his own page. This page is sitting in his home directory and the Apache is configured in such a way that a `VirtualHost` is using that directory as `DocumentRoot`. The access.log and error.log for that `VirtaulHost` are located in `/var/log/apache2` as `VirtualHost` specific files.

All of this is working nicely - but my friend doesn't have permission to read anything inside `/var/log/apache2`, of course.

How can I grant him read permissions for those files without exposing anything else in `/var/log/`?

(The naive `ln -s /var/log/apache2/friend.access.log` in his home directory didn't work, of couse...)

Comment: What are the current permissions for `/var/log/apache2`?

Comment: `drwxr-x---` for `root:adm` (and the same holds for `/var/log`)

Answer (score 1):

To read a file on a Unix system, you need the `x` permission bit on all levels of parent directory, and the `r` permission bit on that file. In your case, for instance, `friend` would need `x` on `/var`, `/var/log`, and `/var/log/apache2`, in addition to `r` on `/var/log/apache2/friend.access.log`. You could do this via ACLs if you don't want to give all users permissions to read files in `/var/log` even if they have `r` permissions on that file and know the exact path.